# How to pull files from git based on any back date?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-push, git-pull

I have a process that generates a file "hi.txt" at multiple path on multiple servers.

```
target-server1:

/opt/tmp/test/hi.txt 
/opt/tmp/log/db/hi.txt 
.... 
....
/opt/tmp/scr/hi.txt

target-server2:

/app/tmp/hi.txt
/app/db/hi.txt
.... 
.... 
/opt/tmp/scr/hi.txt

and likewise.
```

I wish to maintain these "hi.txt" files in git and I should be able to retrive any hi.txt for any given date-time.

Note: installing git on remote servers is not an option.

Below is the approach i took.

I pull (copied) all these "hi.txt" in a particular folder  onto a common server [we call it a jump-server] which is having git and renaming each of the "hi.txt" with an increment value like

```
jump-server: 
/var/common/hi.txt_1 
/var/common/hi.txt_2 
.... 
....
/var/common/hi.txt_43 
/var/common/hi.txt_44
```

I then plan to push these files to git.

The challenge is how do i retrive pull any file of any given date in the past ?

Considering that we may have /var/common/hi.txt_1 filename pushed to git twice on the same date with the same comments.

I'm using local git and gitlab for maintaining files.

What would be a good approach that will help me retrive the files of any given date from git ? Kindly suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

For directory structure on the jump server : I would suggest

```
# under /var/common/ :
server1/tmp/test/hi.txt
server1/tmp/log/db/hi.txt
...
server1/tmp/src/hi.txt
server2/app/tmp/hi.txt
server2/app/db/hi.txt
...
server2/tmp/src/hi.txt
# etc ...
```

Regarding your "how do i retrieve any file of any given date in the past ?",
I'm not sure I understood all of your concerns.

If the job that copies all files to jump server then creates a commit (`git add -A; git commit -m "Updated"`), what you require is built in with git :

- use `git log` to view all commits (with dates and time)
- use `git checkout [xxx]` to see a precise state, or `git show [xxx]:some/file.txt`, or ...

Any graphical viewer (git-kraken, git-extension, ...) will give you a GUI to browse the history and view a precise file at a precise date.